# Google Analytics Sync

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to get an event date and a system write date from an event so that I can sync the data with my server. I can see the date dimension but its only one value and I want to confirm is that the event date or the system date and is there maybe a another dimension to be able to access the system date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics contains / records only one date dimension.   This is the date and time the hit was recorded.

I am not sure why you would think there would be a difference between *event date and a system write date*

Comment: I am using cordova google plus plugin which still records events offline. Therefore a system date and event date would be different.

Comment: Thats not Google analytics.   thats a plugin for google signin.   Google analytics does not store that information so you are not going to see it.

Comment: so what is a good way to sync this so that I dont have to get the same data over and over again?